# Variable is overwritten in asynchronous function with async.forEach loop

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, asynchronous, webdriver-io

I've stumbled upon (or created myself of course) an error that I cannot model in my head. I'm iteratively calling an URL using the webdriverio client with different IDs and parsing the resulting HTML. **However, the `html` variable gets overwritten with the last element in the loop**, which results in the array containing multiple duplicates of the last html variable value:

```
async.forEach(test, function (id, callback) {
  self.url('https://<api-page>?id=' + id).getHTML('table tbody', true).then(function(html) {
          //Parse HTML
          parser.write(html);
          parser.end();

          //Add course to person, proceed to next.
          callback();
  });
}, function (err) {
  self.end().finally();
  res.json(person);
});
```

Parsing is done using the htmlparser2 NPM library. The html variable always returns the last element, even though I can see it going through the different API ids with different data. I would think the error lies at when I get HTML and return it, but I cannot say why nor have any of my fixes worked.

Hopefully someone more skilled than me can see the error.

Thanks in advance,
Chris

### UPDATE/Solution - See solution below

Comment: sounds like you're running into a closure issue

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally figured it out and I missed that async.forEach executes the function in parallel, whereas the function I needed was async.timesSeries, which executes the functions in a loop, waiting for each function to finish before starting the next! I've attached the working code below:

```
async.timesSeries(3, function(n, next) {
  self.url('<api-page>?id=' + n').then(function() {
    console.log("URL Opened");
  }).getHTML('table tbody', true).then(function(html) {
    console.log("getHTML");
    parser.write(html);
    parser.end();
    next();
  });
}, function(err, results) {
  //Add to person object!
  self.end().finally();
  res.json(person);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood quite well the context but the html variable is not overridden, it is just the last chunk that you 've retrieved from the self.url function call. If you want to have the whole result saved in a variable, you should keep append on every loop the result. Probably, you need something like that:

```
var html = '';

async.forEach(test, function (id, callback) {
  self.url('https://<api-page>?id=' + id).getHTML('table tbody', true).then(function (tmpHtml) {
    //Parse HTML
    parser.write(tmpHtml);
    parser.end();

    html += tmpHtml;
    //Add course to person, proceed to next.
    callback();
  });
}, function (err) {
  self.end().finally();
  res.json(person);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for ypur reply Svabael. Is it possible to process html for each getURL->getHTML call? Instead of appending and then processing?

Comment: I need a bit more context to reply to this. What are you trying to achieve? What the parser is doing? To me seems reasonable to move the parser.end(); at the last callback, just before the self.end().finally(); and to remove the line that appends the html (html += tmpHtml;).

Comment: I'm using selenium to parse a series of webpages (calling the url with different ID in the loop), after loading each page, I extract the HTML and parse a table present on that webpage. Within the html parser I save table rows etc. to a JSON object, however, as the html coming into the parse is the same, I simply get the same JSON object for each of the pages (or it overwrites of course?)

Comment: Quick update: I've just tried appending the HTML to a variable, for some reason I still get the last element twice (instead of two separate HTML elements)

Comment: If you put a console.log(tmpHtml) in the self.url, do you have the expected results? Can you post the self.url implementation?

Comment: I think you might have found the problem! If I put console.log in the url-function, then it returns undefined for all iterations, which as I understand, means that it goes through all the urls before it calls getHTML just as many times.

`async.forEach(test, function (id, callback) {
      self.url('<api>' + id).then(function() {
        console.log(result);
      }).getHTML('table tbody', true).then(function(html) {
              result += html;
              callback();
      });
    }, function (err) {
      self.end().finally();
    }); ` but how do I circumvent this?